# Extract an ID that matches the user login from a table on shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, pipe

[image]So, I have all these user login information (service, admin, J009878) and this table you see here comes from another command whose output is this table which I save in file.txt. What I want to achieve is go through that file.txt file (where this table is) and be able to extract the ID that matches with the login information. The login information (which can be J009878, admin or any one of them) comes in a form of variable $user which then have to be used to extract the id that matches that variable.

For example, If my variable user gets a login name or id of J665454, then I want to be able to extract the id of 23 from there. Similarly, if login name of admin is received then id of 4 needs to be extracted and saved in a variable.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your table and make sure it is exactly like the actual data you have. What kind of table is this? A text file with `|` characters? A database table? And HTML table?

Comment: This is a text file basically. Well, this is an output of a different command that I save in a text file and I want to go through that table in that file and get the ID basically

Comment: What is the command that creates the table? It would possibly make more sense to change that command to either 1) perform the actual query that you want to make, or 2) at least format the output in a more machine-friendly manner.

Comment: There's no `J665454` in your sample input so your question is getting less clear. Don't post images or links, just text that we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Your image looks like a screenshot of something outputted from an SQL database. If you have an actual database, it makes more sense to query than to post-process the formatted result of some generic query.  I would guess a query like `SELECT ID FROM table WHERE LOGIN = 'David'` would do it, for example.

Comment: I see you did the opposite of what we suggested and deleted all of the textual sample input/output and left the image thereby giving us nothing to test a potential solution with. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following GNU sed command, assuming that `$person` stores their login name.

```
sed -En "s_\s*\|([0-9]+)\s*\|\s*$person\s*\|.+_\1_p"
```

Example:

```
❯ set person Jack

❯ cat table.txt | sed -En "s_\s*\|([0-9]+)\s*\|\s*$person\s*\|.+_\1_p"
4

❯ set person David

❯ sed -En "s_\s*\|([0-9]+)\s*\|\s*$person\s*\|.+_\1_p" table.txt # also works
32
```

Explanation:

`sed -E -n`: -E sets the extended regex flag, -n makes sed not print unless explicitly told to do so.

`s_<regex>_<replacement>_p`: `s` is the substitute command (the `_` can be any character, I chose `_` for readability). It matches the regex, and replaces it with the replacement. The `p` at the end makes it print, and since we used `-n`, it will only end up printing lines that match.

`\s*\|([0-9]+)\s*\|\s*$person\s*\|.+`: The regex portion of the expression, explained below

| Regex | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `\s*\|` | This matches any number of spaces (just in case the table is proceeded by whitespace) and then a literal `|`. We escape the `|` since `|` has special meaning in regexes. |
| `([0-9]+)` | This matches one or more characters in the range 0-9. In most regex engines, you could also use `\d` for this, but `sed` doesn't support `\d`. The parenthesis around this expression places it into a "group", which we can reference in the replacement using `\1-9`. For example, `echo "hello" | sed "s_([aeiou])/\1\1_g"` would produce `heelloo`, since each vowel is replaced with 2 copies of itself (the g flag makes it work multiple times per line) |
| `\s*\|\s*` | Any amount of space (including none), then a literal `|`, then any amount of space (including none). |
| `$person` | This portion gets replaced by your shell, and is never seen by sed, so this ends up matching the letters `Jack` or whatever `$person` is when the script gets called. |
| `\s*\|` | Any amount of space (including none), then a literal `|`. We have to match these to make sure that `Jackie` doesn't also match when the login we're looking for is `Jack`. |
| `.+` | This matches anything and everything, until the end of the line. This is important, because when we do our replacement, whatever is left unmatched will still end up being printed, so we need to make sure to match the whole line. |

`\1`: We replace whatever the regex matches (which is hopefully the whole line) with group 1, which was the ID number we're after. This ends up leaving the whole line as just that ID number, so we print the line.

Comment: Apparently, this did not work. I have the table in a table.txt file and the ID for the username I am looking for is David. It's not returning anything. Also the table is dynamic and can change based on number of users I have

Comment: Ah, your table was formatted differently when I answered the post. Let me finish my explanation and then I'll try it on the correct formatting and see what I can do to fix it. @BishwashKarki

Comment: @BishwashKarki I used `$person` instead of `$user` in the command, my bad. I tried the command again with the new table and it still works, so switch $person for $user (or whatever variable you want to use, or just the name itself) and give it another shot.

Comment: Did not work! I think it is my fault that how the table has actually been structured was not clear. I should have just inserted an image rather than trying to replicate it. I just updated the question with image, could you please check that let me know. Also, great explanation on the sed command